# Merging two rows in AWK

Tags: awk

I have a data format as follows:

```
Ind1 0 1 2
Ind1 0 2 1
Ind2 1 1 0 
Ind2 2 2 0
```

I want to use AWK to have this output:

```
Ind1 00 12 21
Ind2 12 12 00
```

That is to merge each two rows with the same row names.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com ?

Answer (score 2):

file a.awk:

```
{
    col2[$1] = col2[$1] $2
    col3[$1] = col3[$1] $3
    col4[$1] = col4[$1] $4
}

END {

    for ( i in col2 )
    {
        print i " " col2[i] " " col3[i] " " col4[i]
    }
}
```

run:

`cat data | awk -f a.awk`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my problem is that my real file has more than 1000 rows and about 400, 000 columns, so, I can not use this code.

Answer (score 0):

This version only assumes that all the lines that should be grouped are continguous

```
awk '
    function output() {
        printf "%s", prev
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
            printf "%s%s", OFS, col[i]
        print ""
    }
    $1 != prev {
        if (NR != 1) 
            output()
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
            col[i] = $i
        prev = $1
        next 
    }
    { 
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
            col[i] = col[i] $i 
    }
    END {
        output()
    }
'
```